# Difference of arithmetic series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've been asked to state whether or not this is an arithmetic series and, if so, to give its common difference.

$$n+2n+3n+4n$$

My answer was that it was not an arithmetic series.

I figured this on the basis that the value of each $n$ is equal to its position in the sequence.

However the book stated that it *was* an arithmetic sequence with difference $n$.

I can see why: in the absence of any other information, a letter symbol which is repeated is just assumed to hold the same value.

I suppose that I would have been correct in stating that the sequence was not an arithmetic sequence if it was written like so:

$$n_1+2n_2+3n_3+4n_4$$

Is my supposition correct?

Comment: Yes, the key is that it is the same $n$.

Comment: I thought so. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is a series based on an arithmetic progession by $n$:
$$
x_k = k n \quad S_k = \sum_{i = 0}^k x_i
$$
If the differences $n$ would vary with the sequence index $k$, then it would depend on the specific choices of the $n_k$, what kind of sequence or series would result.